# SignTypedData returns 64 bytes instead of 65

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am using Hardhat and getting 64 bytes when calling `eth_signTypedData_v4`
What can be the issue? On what does it depend?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems related to the source code I was dealing with. It was using `compact` method to get shorter signature